# Script conflict with adminimize plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Thought about asking on wordpress answers, but they would tell me it's a "plugin thing".. If you disagree then feel free to pass it over to them.

I'm using this code in my functions.php which offers a dropdown menu of available categories when a user clicks the new post button. This forces them to choose a category BEFORE the new blank post is created.

The problem is I'm getting "invalid post type" error and have it traced it back to a plugin called "adminimizer".

The new post never gets created, the address bar gets stuck at mysite.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?category_id%5B%5D=4&continue=Continue&post_type=    (it should say "post" after the type=.. and I get an error box saying "invalid post type".

I'd love to hear any thoughts on why my script might not be completing. Here's the code I'm using:

```
//ADD DROPDOWN MENU TO CHOOSE NEW POST CATEGORY (CHOOSE THE CAT ID’S YOU WANT TO APPEAR)
add_filter( 'load-post-new.php', 'wpse14403_load_post_new' );
function wpse14403_load_post_new()
{
$post_type = 'post';
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ) {
    $post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];
}

// Only do this for posts
if ( 'post' != $post_type ) {
    return;
}

if ( array_key_exists( 'category_id', $_REQUEST ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse14403_wp_insert_post' );
    return;
}

// Show intermediate screen
extract( $GLOBALS );
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
$title = $post_type_object->labels->add_new_item;

include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php' );

$dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( array(

'orderby'            => 'name',
'include' => '3, 4',
    'name' => 'category_id[]',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'echo' => false,
) );

$category_label = __( 'Create New' );
$continue_label = __( 'Continue' );
echo <<<HTML
<div class="wrap">

<h2>{$title}</h2>

<form method="get">
    <table class="orange">
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">{$category_label}</th>
                <td>{$dropdown}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <th><input name="continue" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="  {$continue_label}" /></th>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="{$post_type}" />
   </form>
</div>
HTML;
include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-footer.php' );
exit();
}

// This function will only be called when creating an empty post,
// via `get_default_post_to_edit()`, called in post-new.php
function wpse14403_wp_insert_post( $post_id )
{
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $_REQUEST['category_id'] );
}
```

UPDATE / MORE INFO. On further investigation, I changed a bit of my code towards the end from hidden to text. This reveals an input field that is usually automatically filled with the post type "post". The adminimize plugin appears to prevent this from happening, even though I have not set it to hide anything?

```
<input type="text" name="post_type" value="{$post_type}" />
```

I guess the easy solution would be just don't use the adminimizer plugin, but it's very useful to keep things simple for new site owners. I've asked the plugin author about this, but don't expect an answer any time soon - thanks

Comment: Got the answer: Well it turns out that the plugin author (Frank) offers great support. He spotted there was a problem with this line & simply commented it out. Now everything works as expected :) 

    //extract( $GLOBALS );

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that the plugin author (Frank) offers great support. He spotted there was a problem with this line & simply commented it out. Now everything works as expected :)

```
//extract( $GLOBALS );
```

Comment: Yes, great plugin, great author :)